# Minimize python directory/modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

The main issue:
I'm building a Python project.
The Project will be compiled to an .exe including its entire Python environment - so I want it to be as minimal as possible.

**One idea:**
I had installed a lot of modules I don't (currently/will) use.
I want to run a script (python/batch/bash/Pycharm plugin) that will coverage all used/unused modules so i can uninstall them.

*-Is there a way to do it?*
And for all used modules - to delete codes, functions, objects which are not needed.

*-Is there a way to do even this?*

**Any other ideas?**

Comment: There are two questions, 1 deleting unused packages. for this I would create a new virtual environment, try to run the code (including build with pyinstaller or whatever youre using) and add missing packages until everything works. You should be smart here if there is code that takes long time to trigger (like midnight jobs or anything like that).

Comment: Your second problem sounds like striping, I had never listen to anything about it in python, would be intersting to see this.

Comment: Take a look at vulture https://pypi.org/project/vulture/

Comment: What tool will you use to compile your Python project to an executable?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can use [pyflakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes)

```
pyflakes project.py

Example output:

project.py:1: 'app.SomeClass' imported but unused
```